# CSS3 background image transition

Tags: css, background, background-image, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a "fade-in fade-out" effect using the CSS transition. But I can't get this to work with the background image...

The CSS:

```css
.title a {
    display: block;
    width: 340px;
    height: 338px;
    color: black;
    background: transparent;
    /* TRANSITION */
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
    transition: background 1s;
}

.title a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p1nr1fkWKUo/T0zUp5CLO3I/AAAAAAAAAWg/jDiQ0cUBuKA/s800/red-pattern.png) repeat;
    /* TRANSITION */
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
    transition: background 1s;
}​
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/AK3La/

Answer (score 113):

You can transition `background-image`. Use the CSS below on the `img` element:

```css
-webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

This is supported natively by Chrome, Opera and Safari. Firefox hasn't implemented it yet ([bugzil.la](http://bugzil.la/546052)). Not sure about IE.

Comment: `background-image` is not an animatable property (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties), so your solution is not standard compliant.

Comment: This is not a solution - FF and IE do not support it, and as noted above it's not a property the spec says should be supported.

Comment: See also for current development in Fx: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052

Comment: @TLindig It should be an animatable property.

Comment: @Hengjie How did you know webkit browsers supported `transition: background-image`? Source?

Comment: What if I have multiple background images? Can I somehow only address one of the background images to animate?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) background-image is an animatable property. Perhaps this has changed since 2014?

Comment: @Coquelicot it must have been added to that list by mistake because it has since been removed.

Comment: The animatable property is `background`, and this is what should be used (it works in Chrome for me). Maybe the spec (or the impl) has changed since the question was posted

Comment: I am working with this atm and can confirm transition of "background-image" working on Chrome and Safari. It adds a nice touch and I wish FF and IE would implement it as well.

Comment: @TLindig's link is dead. The animation type of [`background-image`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#propdef-background-image) can be referenced [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations-1/#animation-types).

Answer (score 37):

The solution (that I found by myself) is a ninja trick, I can offer you two ways:

first you need to make a "container" for the `<img>`, it will contain *normal* and *hover* states at the same time:

```
<div class="images-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/9/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/10/">
</div>
```

- with **CSS3** selectors http://jsfiddle.net/eD2zL/1/ (if you use this one, "normal" state will be first child your container, or change the `nth-child()` order)
- **CSS2** solution http://jsfiddle.net/eD2zL/2/ (differences between are just a few selectors)

Basically, you need to hide "normal" state and show their "hover" when you *hover it*

and that's it, I hope somebody find it useful.

Comment: Nice solution.

When experimenting with the first sample, I noticed that if you increase the transition duration to 4s, you can see a very noticable jump when the z-index switches in the middle of the transition.  At least on Chrome 35, you can shift the timing of the z-index switch and clean up the transition by changing the property value to "all 4s ease, z-index 1ms" (http://jsfiddle.net/eD2zL/330/).

Comment: @NealS. you're right. This answer is 2 years old though, I would remove z-index, it seems unnecessary. The images just need to be in order.

Comment: Is possible "lazy loading" if I use this solution?

Comment: I updated this solution using flex grid and no z-index jump: https://jsfiddle.net/khsejL5p/

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately you can't use transition on `background-image`, see the [w3c list of animatable properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animation-of-property-types-).

You may want to do some tricks with `background-position`.

Comment: Nice idea !

Answer (score 17):

I've figured out a solution that worked for me...

If you have a list item (or div) containing only the link, and let's say this is for social links on your page to facebook, twitter, ect. and you're using a sprite image you can do this:

```
<li id="facebook"><a href="facebook.com"></a></li>
```

Make the "li"s background your button image

```
#facebook {
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   background:url(images/social) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

Then make the link's background image the hover state of the button. Also add the opacity attribute to this and set it to 0.

```
#facebook a {
   display:inline-block;
   background:url(images/social) no-repeat 0px -30px;
   opacity:0;
}
```

Now all you need is "opacity" under "a:hover" and set this to 1.

```
#facebook a:hover {
   opacity:1;
}
```

Add the opacity transition attributes for each browser to "a" and "a:hover" so the the final css will look something like this:

```
#facebook {
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   background:url(images/social) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
#facebook a {
   display:inline-block;
   background:url(images/social) no-repeat 0px -30px;
   opacity:0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   -moz-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   -o-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   -ms-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}
#facebook a:hover {
   opacity:1;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   -moz-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   -o-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   -ms-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
   transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}
```

If I explained it correctly that should let you have a fading background image button, hope it helps at least!

Comment: I also made a video tutorial version of it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ieR5ApVpr0

Comment: You shouldn't, AFAIK, need to specify the transitions on the hover pseudoclass; the transition definition for the anchor tag type will carry forward to the hover behavior, all you need to change is the opacity. Keep in mind that this example works well because the styles are applied directly to IDs/tag types; if you do this with classes, you have to make sure you aren't adding and removing the class with the transition defined.

Answer (score 16):

You can use pseudo element to get the effect you want like I did in that [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evpg3qdm/).

CSS:

```
.title a {
    display: block;
    width: 340px;
    height: 338px;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.title a:after {
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p1nr1fkWKUo/T0zUp5CLO3I/AAAAAAAAAWg/jDiQ0cUBuKA/s800/red-pattern.png) repeat;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* TRANSISITION */
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.title a:hover:after{   
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="title">
    <a href="#">HYPERLINK</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, but you may run into 2 problems: 1) if you don't see the `:after` element, try setting `width` and `height` as `100%` instead of `inherit`, 2) if the `background-image` is actually displayed in _foreground_, use negative index for the `:after` element: `z-index: -1;`

Answer (score 11):

Considering background-images can't be animated,
I created a little SCSS mixin allowing to transition between 2 different background-images using pseudo selectors **before** and **after**. They are at different z-index layers. The one that is ahead starts with opacity 0 and becomes visible with hover.

You can use it the same approach for creating animations with linear-gradients too.

## scss

```
@mixin bkg-img-transition( $bkg1, $bkg2, $transTime:0.5s ){  
  position: relative;  
  z-index: 100; 
  &:before, &:after {
    background-size: cover;  
    content: '';    
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;    
    width: 100%;    
    transition: opacity $transTime;
  }
  &:before {    
    z-index: -101;
    background-image: url("#{$bkg1}");    
  }
  &:after {    
    z-index: -100;
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url("#{$bkg2}");    
  }
  &:hover {
     &:after{
       opacity: 1; 
     }
  }  
}
```

Now you can simply use it with

```
@include bkg-img-transition("https://picsum.photos/300/300/?random","https://picsum.photos/g/300/300");
```

You can check it out here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pablosgpacheco/01rmg0qL/

Comment: Very nice solution! Gave me a better understanding of how to make good use of the element states ':before' and ':after' as a bonus :-)

Answer (score 10):

If you can use jQuery, you can try [BgSwitcher](https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher) plugin to switch the background-image with effects, it's very easy to use.

For example :

```
$('.bgSwitch').bgswitcher({
        images: ["style/img/bg0.jpg","style/img/bg1.jpg","style/img/bg2.jpg"],
        effect: "fade",
        interval: 10000
});
```

And add your own effect, see [adding an effect types](https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher#adding-an-effect-types)

Comment: Thanks, I'v solved the issue with animating of table background change with use of this plugin.

Answer (score 8):

Try this, will make the background animated worked on web but hybrid mobile app
not working

```
@-webkit-keyframes breath {
 0%   {  background-size: 110% auto; }
 50%  {  background-size: 140% auto; }
 100% {  background-size: 110% auto; }      
}
body {
   -webkit-animation: breath 15s linear infinite;
   background-image: url(images/login.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If animating `opacity` is not an option, you can also animate `background-size`.

For example, I used this CSS to set a `backgound-image` with a delay.

```
.before {
  background-size: 0;
}

.after {
  transition: background 0.1s step-end;
  background-image: $path-to-image;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: If you want a fade-out effect from `.after` into `.before` for the background image, you must set the background image into the `.before`. Otherwise it will just disappear without animation.

Answer (score 3):

Salam, this answer works only in Chrome, cause IE and FF support color transition.

There is no need to make your HTML elements `opacity:0`, cause some times they contain text, and no need to double your elements!.

The question with link to an example in jsfiddle needed a small change, that is to put an empty image in `.title a` like `background:url(link to an empty image);` same as you put it in `.title a:hover` but make it empty image, and the code will work.

```
.title a {
display: block;
width: 340px;
height: 338px;
color: black;
background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Empty.png) repeat;
/* TRANSISITION */
transition: background 1s;
-webkit-transition: background 1s;
-moz-transition: background 1s;
-o-transition: background 1s;
  }
  .title a:hover{   background: transparent;
   background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p1nr1fkWKUo/T0zUp5CLO3I/AAAAAAAAAWg/jDiQ0cUBuKA/s800/red-pattern.png) repeat;
/* TRANSISITION */
transition: background 1s;
-webkit-transition: background 1s;
-moz-transition: background 1s;
-o-transition: background 1s;
}
```

Check this out  https://jsfiddle.net/Tobasi/vv8q9hum/

Comment: Still not working on fire fox or IE :(, but looks fine in chrome

Answer (score 2):

With Chris's inspiring post here:

https://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/

I managed to come up with this:

```
#banner
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center bottom;
    background-image:url(../images/image1.jpg);
    /* HOVER OFF */
    @include transition(background-image 0.5s ease-in-out); 

    &:hover
    {
        background-image:url(../images/image2.jpg);
        /* HOVER ON */
        @include transition(background-image 0.5s ease-in-out); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with greater cross-browser support than the accepted answer by using pseudo-elements as exemplified by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19818268/2602816

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a bit, I first used a stack of images on top of each other and every three seconds, I was trying to animate to the next image in the stack and throwing the current image to the bottom of the stack. At the same time I was using animations as shown above. I couldn't get it to work for the life of me.

You can use this library which allows for **dynamically-resized, slideshow-capable background image ** using jquery-backstretch.

https://github.com/jquery-backstretch/jquery-backstretch