# jQuery fadeout image

Tags: jquery

I have a code to change image for every fixed intervals but this image is just normally changing. How can I use fadeout option to my code so that it will slowly fadeout to open a new image. My code follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        (function() {
            var curImgId = 0;
            var numberOfImages = 2;
            window.setInterval(function() {
                $('body').css('background-image','url(bg' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
                curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
            }, 15 * 100);
        })();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fade background images.. You can only fade elements (*but fading the `body` will fade all contents as well*)

You will need to add it as an element and put it behind all others.. and fade that element with [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this thread:
 [CSS3 background image transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition).
It's a nice solution with css.

Answer (score 0):

You could fade the opacity of the element to zero, then change the background-image, then fade it back to 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        (function() {
            var curImgId = 0;
            var numberOfImages = 2;
            window.setInterval(function() {
                $('body').fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
                    $(this).css('background-image','url(bg' + curImgId + '.jpg)');
                    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
                });
                curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
            }, 15 * 100);
        })();
 });
```