# transition for background-image in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to find an alternative for this:

`"transition:background-image 1s whatever"`

in **firefox** since it only works on webkit browsers.

I already tried the opacity alternative but thats not an option for me since i have content on the background container which will disappear along with the background if using opacity.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Background image Transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition)

Comment: No, its not because the solution offered there is the opacity thing and as i said on my post that wont work for me.

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619705/1873387 It looks like firefox hasn't implemented it yet.

Comment: I know that man, thats why im asking for an alternative.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do that using 2 pseudo elements

CSS

```
.test
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.test:before, .test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.test:before {
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.test:after {
    background-color: green;
}

.test:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

### [fiddle with real images](http://jsfiddle.net/uheeswap/)

(hover to transition)

To be able to see the div content, the pseudo elements need to be in negative z-index:

### [fiddle with corrected z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/BXLkx/1/)

looks like IE won't trigger this hover

```
.test:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

but will trigger this one

```
.test:hover {
}
.test:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

(As SILLY as it seems)

[fiddle for IE10](http://jsfiddle.net/BXLkx/3/)

Comment: Hi, that looks nice but i cant place content within the div?

Comment: You are right, I forget to check that. I have added another example, where I set the z-index to negative values and corrects that problem.

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! Thank you. And now just as bonus. Does it work for the latest version of IE? I have 9 and it doesnt work here. Not that i care much because IE sucks though.

Comment: After 10 minutes trying, get it to work with IE10. Hopefully, it will work also on 9 ..

Comment: Wow, Explorer really is a piece of shit. I cant believe its necessary to come up with a lot of odd code in order to make things work there. Seems like it wont work on explorer 9. But nevermind, i gave up explorer long time ago anyway. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: do remember that after and before psuedo-elements will not work on inputs, such as submit buttons, where an effect like this is often desirable

Comment: I put +1 here, BUT NOW I NEED TO IMPLEMENT ALL THESE IN MY PROJECT, anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Easiest solution making use of hover

```css
 

.self-pic {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity, 1s;
}

img.front:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="self-pic">
  <img class="back" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/350*350" />
  <img class="front" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/351*351" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It does work

You can see it here : http://dabblet.com/gist/1931619

But apparently Firefox hasn't implemented it yet.

Comment: Thanks, but thats what my question is about. Since ti doesnt work on firefox im looking for alternatives.

Comment: @CainNuke Ok sorry. I guess the only thing you could do would be to have an empty div only containing the background image and another div on top containing the content... I can't think of another alternative.

Comment: Yes, but if you do that and apply opacity transition then the content will disappear too.

Comment: No you only apply the transition to the div containing the background picture, and nothing else

Comment: How do you do that? When i hove everything inside the div disappears, not only the background.

Comment: Yes, so you should have a containing div, and inside that div one div containing only the background, and on top of it, one div containing the content. This isn't great but that's all I've got.

Answer (score -2):

```
#id_of_element {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Does this not do it? Just need to change the all to background-image.

Comment: No, it doesnt. Firefox doesnt support transition for background-image. Thats why im asking for an alternative.

Comment: From what i can find, it doesn't seem there is a workaround for this yet.

Comment: It's the end of 2021 and FF _still_ doesn't support it! 