# BackgroundImage transition doesn't work on firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, transition

I use transition in javascript but doesn't work on firefox, someone know why ? Is good on google chrome.
This is my code :

```
el.style.backgroundImage = "url('menu.jpg')";
el.style.transition = "background 0.4s";
```

Comment: Curious as to why you're putting the transition in Javascript in the first place? Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808764/transition-for-background-image-in-firefox

Comment: because i want this effect www.kakoum.fr (on menu hover)

Comment: You can put the transition in the CSS and still have it appear when you modify it in the JS. also look at the post I linked you to

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestion at link posted by @Jeremy ; substituted setting `transition` to affect `background-size` for `opacity`

```css
div a {
  color: #fff;
  z-Index: 3;
  position: absolute;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: background-size 0.4s;
}
div:before {
  background: #1F1F1F;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
div:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature);
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}
div:hover:before {
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}
div:hover:after {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#">abc</a>
</div>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/XJMvtEnuvS1TF1xqIVVQ?p=preview

Comment: @Kakoum Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: @Kakoum What is expected result ?

Comment: Look my siteweb www.kakoum.fr on firefox and googlechrome (mouse on menu)