# background-image transition not working?

Tags: html, css, transition

I need to do just a simple transition of background img, but searching for tutorials I found out a way to do it. 
But its not working? Don't know why?

```
#chat
{
    background-image:url(chat.png);
    width:91px;
    height:40px;
    float:right;
    transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
#chat:hover
{
    background-image:url(hchat.png);
    width:91px;
    height:40px;

}
```

Link of code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xscsz5c0/2/

Is there something, I am missing? Coz I am not that good in CSS!

Comment: `background-image` is not an animation property.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Seems like it doesn't work in all browsers

Comment: It is not necessary to re-declare height and width properties on `:hover` when their value does not change (only re-declare when something changes).

Comment: @neilhem I use Firefox!

Comment: @KheemaPandey then what should I do?? should I change my entire code??

Comment: @user3672971 transitioning background-image does not work in Firefox yet. The same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because background transition doesn't work in Firefox, here's a workaround (which also gets around the problem of the hover image not loading with the page): http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/azHli

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#chat
{
    background:url(http://i62.tinypic.com/29or6z6.png);
    width:91px;
    height:40px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;  
}

#chat::after
{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://i57.tinypic.com/i26j3b.png);
    width:91px;
    height:40px;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
}

#chat:hover::after
{
    opacity: 1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a id="chat" href="chat.php"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remember that you have to hover for 5 seconds to see the transition—unless you reduce the time.

Comment: I kept it 5s just to encounter the change! :) It would be better to check with 5s first!

Comment: Hm, just checked in FF and it doesn't seem to work with a bg image, although it's fine with plain colors. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to deal with this is with a jQuery plugin called anystretch. You will need to download the anystretch js file and add it to your project. You will also need to have jquery.

I love anystretch because it replaces the target div with a specified image but also lets you chose a fadeIn time for it.

I had issues with using the css transition because it's cross-browser functionality was horrible.

sample on codepen http://codepen.io/cwilliams23/pen/iIomJ

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chat").mouseenter(function() {
      $("#chat").anystretch("http://i57.tinypic.com/i26j3b.png", {speed: 200});   
    $("#chat").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).anystretch("http://i62.tinypic.com/29or6z6.png", {speed: 1000});
    });
    });
 });
```

You can play with the fade times to make it fade the way you want. The speed settings are in ms so 5s would be 5000.

Answer (score -1):

Add display:inline-block to your code:

```
#chat:hover
{
    background-image:url(http://i57.tinypic.com/i26j3b.png);
    width:91px;
    height:40px;
   display:inline-block;

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xscsz5c0/4/)