# Is there a way to use "transition: background-image" for opacity only?

Tags: css, image, background, transition, opacity

As far as I can tell, "transition: background-image" affects multiple CSS properties, including scale and opacity, without bias. See example below. I wish to affect opacity only. Is this possible within the transition parameters?

`View`[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/marbinjavier/jcyx9e42/).

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition).
It looks like background-image isn't animatable, at least the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties) says that.
Take a look at the other question, it has a jquery plugin that does this.