# CSS Transition not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, transition

I've been working on my special hover effect for my button, but the problem is, it's not working on Firefox, but it works on chrome smoothly.

```
#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_sellers{
    background:url('images/hs_sl_bg.png') center top no-repeat;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_buyers{
    background:url('images/hs_sl_bg.png') center top no-repeat;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_senior{
    background:url('images/hs_sl_bg.png') center top no-repeat;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_divorce{
    background:url('images/hs_dl_bg.png') center top no-repeat;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_construction{
    background:url('images/hs_dl_bg.png') center top no-repeat;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_sellers:hover{
    background:url('images/hs_sellers.png') center top no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 1s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
    -o-transition: 1s all ease;
    -ms-transition: 1s all ease;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_buyers:hover{
    background:url('images/hs_buyers.png') center top no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 1s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
    -o-transition: 1s all ease;
    -ms-transition: 1s all ease;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_senior:hover{
    background:url('images/hs_senior.png') center top no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 1s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
    -o-transition: 1s all ease;
    -ms-transition: 1s all ease;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_divorce:hover{
    background:url('images/hs_divorce.png') center top no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 1s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
    -o-transition: 1s all ease;
    -ms-transition: 1s all ease;
}

#hotsheet_wrapper .hs_construction:hover{
    background:url('images/hs_construction.png') center top no-repeat;
    transition: 1s all ease;
    -moz-transition: 1s all ease;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
    -o-transition: 1s all ease;
    -ms-transition: 1s all ease;
}
```

Comment: have you tried this notation: `-moz-transition:all` .1s ease; ?

Comment: yes bro, still not working :(

Comment: transition must be set to no hover element

Comment: hi @fcastillo, still not working :(

Comment: here you have a good example [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition)

Comment: @fcastillo, problem still existing :(

Comment: Well, then I suggest you that you use two divs with backgrounds different but one of them with opacity 0 and in hover do a transition to opacity 1.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d2gmmmr/) example

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052

However, you can use CSS `opacity` or JS/jQuery to get similar effects. Check out the following pure CSS solution.

```css
.element {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
.element:before,
.element:after {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.element:before {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
    transition: opacity 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}
.element:after {
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1);
}
.element:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```