# How can I prevent the stutter that occurs while transitioning background-image?

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I am using `background-size: cover; transition: background-image 4s;` on an element and I have written some JS that changes the `background-image` property every 10 seconds.

The element transitions the background image in webkit browsers but the image shakes while transitioning.

How can I prevent that?

Here is a JSFiddle with an example of the behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelynch/x60gL1p6/

Comment: show us example on jsfiddle

Comment: What kind of transition do you do? What property?

Comment: "stutter"? "shakes"? You mean it changes position?

Comment: I didn't think that `background-image` **was** actually animatable/transitionable with CSS...so I'm not sure what the heck is going on. Yep...it's not [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: @taesu: I have updated the question with an example.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Yes, you can transition background-image in webkit browsers.

Comment: Is there an official source for that? If it's experimental (as I suspect) then bugs are to be expected.

Comment: @Paulie_D http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619705/2262604

Comment: @MichaelLynch I'm still waiting for an **official** source.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't have one, and I understand that this may be experimental, but I'm still curious if there is a solution to the problem. Obviously webkit has implemented `transition: background-image` because it's working. It's just not working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using background-size: cover;, use in % like                     background-size: 100% 190%;