# Slideshow FireFox

Tags: css, slideshow

I'm trying to do a simple slideshow using CSS, that would work fine cross browser.
Here's what I've tried, and it works in all browsers. It was basically taken from W3schools website :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {background: yellow;}
    25%  {background: green;}
    50%  {background: pink;}
    75%  {background: orange;}
    100% {background: blue;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {background: yellow;}
    25%  {background: green;}
    50%  {background: pink;}
    75%  {background: orange;}
    100% {background: blue;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this works fine cross browser. But once I try to change the animation to 'rotate' background-images it works in chrome, but it wouldn't work in FireFox

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {background-image: url(slideshow/01.jpg);}
    25%  {background-image: url(slideshow/02.jpg);}
    50%  {background-image: url(slideshow/03.jpg);}
    75%  {background-image: url(slideshow/04.jpg);}
    100% {background-image: url(slideshow/05.jpg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {background-image: url(slideshow/01.jpg);}
    25%  {background-image: url(slideshow/02.jpg);}
    50%  {background-image: url(slideshow/03.jpg);}
    75%  {background-image: url(slideshow/04.jpg);}
    100% {background-image: url(slideshow/05.jpg);}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 background image transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition)

Comment: Although not pure css this will work in all browsers. http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/18