# crossfade two background images with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to cross fade the two images as they are called with the setInterval.  Right now they are coming in right away.  Is there a way to crossfade the image that is currently loaded with the new random image that is called?

```
  <script>
      $(function () {
          var imageArray = ['BG-1.jpg', 'BG-2.jpg', 'BG-3.jpg', 'BG-4.jpg', 'BG-5.jpg', 'BG-6.jpg', 'BG-7.jpg', 'BG-8.jpg', 'BG-9.jpg', 'BG-10.jpg', 'BG-11.jpg', 'BG-12.jpg', 'BG-13.jpg', 'BG-14.jpg', 'BG-15.jpg', 'BG-16.jpg', 'BG-17.jpg', 'BG-18.jpg', 'BG-19.jpg', 'BG-20.jpg', 'BG-21.jpg', 'BG-22.jpg']
          $('#background').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/Content/img/BackGround/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' })
          setInterval(function () {
              $('#background').css({ 'background-image': 'url(/Content/img/BackGround/' + imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)] + ')', 'background-size': 'cover' })
          }, 10000);
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: You'd need two elements.

Comment: Yes, ish http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619705/2531091