# CSS Slider does not work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I try to make a little slider, but it works only in Google Chrome.

In FireFox (version 47) it doesn't work.

The CSS file is that:

```
#home-container {
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background-image: url("img1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

and the HTML (with a little script):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script>
        var index = 0;
        function changeImage() {
            var imgArr = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'];
            document.getElementById("home-container").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgArr[index] + "')";
            index++;
            if (index >= imgArr.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
        }
        setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home-container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: I need a solution for that code, not an alternative to use jQuery.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - how do you mean? Is there an error? Is the behaviour unexpected? @Doro

Comment: The behavior it isn't what should have to be. For example, in Chrome the images are changed with a slide effect, but in Firefox are instantly changed without any effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox won't support it according to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052) nor is it an animatable property (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties).

See [this awswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition) for details.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can u try to add transition-delay (4th parameter) equal 0, into all properties?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I need a side effect, not a delay... I think I will build it with jQuery....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can play with the opacity attribute. Check this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/opacity.html is a way to set opacity in all elemnts.