# CSS transition on background image change of DIV

Tags: html, css

I tried to apply transition property to give an effect when image changes on hover but it seems to not work. Please have a look and help me out.

```
.ow-outer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-image: url(../images/team-canada-light.png);
    background-size: 120px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.ow-outer:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/team-canada.png);
}
```

Comment: There's no transition in the code. Show us what you tried, don't expect us to write things for you.

Comment: as @junkfoodjunkie said, no code = no answers

Comment: oh yes! my bad.. updated...

Comment: it wont work, transition only works for properties with integers (heights, widths, margins, color[rgba] )

Comment: I don't know if you made any research before posting your question here, but here is a thread with few working solution/workarounds for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition

Answer (score 8):

Transition on `background-image` doesn't work cross browser, so use a pseudo element  instead

Using `opacity`

```css
.ow-outer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200)  no-repeat center;
    background-size: 120px;
}
.ow-outer::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; right:0; bottom: 0;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200/f00) no-repeat center;
    background-size: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.ow-outer:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ow-outer"></div>
```

Using `transform: scale`

```css
.ow-outer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200)  no-repeat center;
    background-size: 120px;
}
.ow-outer::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; right:0; bottom: 0;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200/f00) no-repeat center;
    background-size: inherit;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.ow-outer:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="ow-outer"></div>
```

Comment: I tested the `opacity` code and works perfect, this solution is beautiful

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Used images from some example..

```css
.bgImg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/tmM8Bpy.jpg);
  -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
  transition: background-image 0.5s linear;
}

.bgImg:hover {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/FWqOONj.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bgImg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use opacity for transitions. It doesnt work with images

Answer (score 0):

Use `background` css property instead of `background-image` property it will work...

```css
    .ow-outer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: url('https://www.hello.com/img_/hello_logo_hero.png');
    background-size: 120px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
.ow-outer:hover {
    background: url('https://images.chesscomfiles.com/uploads/v1/blog/287126.d6272c47.630x354o.36990d3fc701.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="ow-outer"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference.