# Transition between background images that works the same across all modern browsers?

Tags: css

I'm trying to fade in/out the background images using CSS.

I'm using CSS `transitions` for this purpose.

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;
```

The code above works fine in Chrome but it doesn't not work at all in Firefox at all!

[A WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/852822/)

Click on the **'Apple' text** to view the transition in chrome.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: only two images?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, very good question. No. i have 3 different images. but I just minified my code for the purpose of this question.

Comment: It's because firefox doesn't yet support `background-image` as an [animate-able property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) but there's simple workarounds possible.

Comment: @ChrisW. can you please let me know the possible workaround?

Comment: Here's [some options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition) or I can make something custom later when I have more time, either way cheers and welcome to SO :)

Comment: @ChrisW. cheers. absolutely nothing works. all of those Answers in your link mention 1 or 2 browsers that their solution wont work in. I need something that works across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider pseudo element in order to create different layer then you can use `opacity` for the fade:

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1069);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.box:before {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1045);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:after {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1049);
  transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
}

.box.animate::before {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
}
.box.animate::after {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

And in case you want another kind of animation you can play with `background-size` and multiple background:

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: 
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069),
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1045),
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1049),
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1051);
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.box:hover {
  animation:change 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes change {
  0%  {background-size:100% 100%,100% 100%,100% 100%,100% 100%;}
  25% {background-size:0    0   ,100% 100%,100% 100%,100% 100%;}
  50% {background-size:0    0   ,0    0   ,100% 100%,100% 100%;}
  75% {background-size:0    0   ,0    0   ,0    0   ,100% 100%;}
  100%{background-size:0    0   ,0    0   ,0    0   ,0    0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can also adjust `background-position` to create different way of transition:

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: 
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069),
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1045),
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1049),
    url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1051);
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-position:left;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.box:hover {
  animation:change 2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes change {
  0%  {background-size:100% 100%,100% 100%,100% 100%,100% 100%;}
  25% {background-size:0    100%,100% 100%,100% 100%,100% 100%;}
  50% {background-size:0    100%,0    100%,100% 100%,100% 100%;}
  75% {background-size:0    100%,0    100%,0    100%,100% 100%;}
  100%{background-size:0    100%,0    100%,0    100%,0    100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: How can i use this menthod using a jquery click function similar to what I have in my example?

Comment: @JamesJuanjie I used the hover state, so simply change the hover with a class and add that class

Comment: @JamesJuanjie I updated the code to add click event and added another method

Comment: its nice but what i need to do is to change the background image based on which button is clicked. But your examples, uses before/after and it goes through the whole images after the click/hover..

Comment: Basically, I have 3 buttons and each button should change the background image to a different image.

Comment: @JamesJuanjie you can adjust it :) it's a simple example .. you can fade only the after, or only the before, or both, etc .. you are free. You have 3 layers and you can do what you want

Comment: I understand. and I have tried that: https://jsfiddle.net/r4n03of5/ but I don't understand how I can use multiple buttons.

Comment: still not exactly what i am trying to do. because with that code, I can only have two buttons. my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/r4n03of5/2/ Also, there is a flashinng/blinking of the first image between the fade in/out animation.

Comment: @JamesJuanjie no need `three` class, simply remove one and two .. here is https://jsfiddle.net/r4n03of5/3/