# Creating a responsive image map with hover effects

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, responsive

I have seen a few tutorials online but none of them truly lead to what I want. My home page can be seen here:

https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/

Basically the main image when you load (https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Front-Page-Image-1.jpg) is a t shirt. I am trying to make it such that when you hover over that shirt then it transitions to the following image which is identical but a red shirt with letters on it as shown here:

https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Front-Page-Image-2.jpg

My site is a wordpress site and this main image is apart of a slider plugin and therefore I am using javascript to add the html for the second image. I have created the following area map

```
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Front-Page-Image-1.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
<area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="515,91,553,72,661,21,804,18,928,67,979,92,1043,154,1130,218,1034,332,994,318,982,335,997,537,1003,682,1004,747,803,759,638,755,513,751,506,444,502,341,479,347,382,239" shape="poly">
</map>
```

My javascript creates a hover over the entire image but I need it to be over the area map and I am trying to make it a smooth transition like a fade in. My JS is as follows:

```
function setUpClickMeImage() {
var image = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner .image');

if (image) {
    // Need to wrap the image div in a link
    var parent = image.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(image);

    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.href = 'https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/shop/';

    newLink.appendChild(image);
    parent.appendChild(newLink);

    // This will force the 2nd image to load so that it is ready to show
    image.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Front-Page-Image-2.jpg')";

    // Put the original image back after 1 ms so that it will appear first, but 2nd image will still be preloaded and ready to show
    setTimeout(function() {
        image.style['background-image'] = "url('https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Front-Page-Image-1.jpg')";
    }, 1);

    // Bring the link to the front so nothing is in its way
    newLink.style.zIndex = 50;
    image.style.zIndex = 50;

    // Add the events for mouseover and mouseleave
    image.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() { 
        image.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Front-Page-Image-2.jpg')";
    });

    image.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() { 
        image.style['background-image'] = "url('https://www.shuanandlebowitz.website/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Front-Page-Image-1.jpg')";
    });
}
}

jQuery(function($) {
  setUpClickMeImage();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this with the HTML structure you have is using CSS [transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition). Specifically, adding one line of CSS (which can be done in JS). For example:

`image.style.transition = "background-image 200ms ease-in-out";`

[image: website hover]