# transition 2s not working for linear-gradient()

Tags: html, css

Hello i have this `div` with `linear-gradient()`.

On hover the div takes 2 seconds to expand to 200px width and to ad blue and green
to the `linear-gradient()`.

But blue and green are added immediately while it does take 2 seconds to expand.

Does anyone know the answer to that.

Here is my code.

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red, yellow);
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}
div:hover {
  width: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red, yellow, blue, green);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also i would like the blue to appear first and then the green.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 background image transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to change the background image, just make it be the final size, and let the growing div show more or less of it

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red, yellow 100px, blue, green);
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}
div:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought there was a bug with my avatar when I say your answer :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am not sure that I understand you. You mean, because I seldom post answers lately ?

Comment: no, we posted the *exact* same answer at the *exact* same time and when I went back to review I got a bit surprised ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use background size for transition `linear-gradient`, because `linear-gradient` can not transition.

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, red, yellow, blue, green);
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}
div:hover {
  width: 200px;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```