# How to prevent a hover animation from ending abruptly once I hover out?

Tags: html, css

I have the following 2 classes:

```
.background-image {
    background-image: url('../assets/artworkNight.png');
    transition-property: background-image;
    transition-duration: 10s;
}
.background-image:hover {
    background-image: url('../assets/artworkDay.png');
}
```

So whenever I hover on `.background-image` the background begins to slowly change over the course of 10 seconds. The problem is that if I unhover the image during second 4-5, it abruptly transitions back to the original image. I was wondering if it's possible to make to transition out the same way it transitions in. For example:

If I hover for 4 seconds, then unhover, I'd want it to take 4 seconds before it completely reverts back to the original image. Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 background image transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#pic1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
#pic2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: opacity 10s;
}
#pic2:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://static.toiimg.com/photo/72975551.cms' alt="pic1" id="pic1"/>
<img src='https://neilpatel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-editing-tools.jpg' alt="pic2" id="pic2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how to achieve this only with css other than including more elements.

Maybe this helps anyway.

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
}

.background,
.background-image1,
.background-image2 {
  height: 400px;
}

.background-image1{
    background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/d92ed9/d92ed9');
    position: relative;
    transition: opacity 4s ease;
}

.background-image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/000000);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 4s ease;
}

.background .background-image1:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.background .background-image2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="background-image1"></div>
  <div class="background-image2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the transition-timing-function. These might give you what you're looking for.

```
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

Or

```
transition-timing-function: linear;
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-image` is not an animatable property. As a workaround, you can use `::before` selector, and use `opacity`  transition between the main element and its `::before` selector.
Also, the requirement is satisfied with one single element.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.background-image {
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/03/26/17/50/sunset-298850_960_720.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
}

.background-image::before {
  content: "";
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/02/14/07/28/painting-3995999_960_720.jpg") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 10s;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.background-image:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

Comment: [Animatable CSS Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)