# Hover gradient and background image with smooth in and out transition

Tags: html, css

**Hover gradient and background image with smooth in and out transition**

so I am making a website. background-color: #212121; that has come to have a hover gradient with the background image with smooth in and out transition.

now, the transition is not smooth. It is flashing.
But one thing without changing the position and size of the .amsecta. can you help me?

```
     <section class="m-containera">
        <div class="am-secta">
          <div class="contenta">
            <div class="titls">Stream your favourite <br class="inlin md:hidden"> tracks right now</div>
            <div class="par"> <i class="fab fa-spotify">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Spotify Playlist</div>
          </div>
          <div class="iframe-container">
            <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/6ffL1W3QlzZGnP90Ffi3kY?theme=0" frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
          body{
  background-color: 212121;
}
.iframe-container {
   
padding-top: 29.25%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .iframe-container iframe {
    border: 0;
    height: 360px;
    left: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .iframe-container iframe:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 160%);
}

.m-containera {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1517px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
 .am-secta {
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      background-color: #212121;
      z-index: 1;
      transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .am-secta:hover{  
     background-image:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(33,33,33,1) 0%, rgba(29,185,84,0.5) 100%), 
     url("http://www.piyushcares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/homepagevid.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat; /*if you have full size image then use no-repeat*/
     background-position: center center top;
     background-size:cover;
    }
.contenta {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.titls {
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}
.par {  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
}
.inlin {
  display: none;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Please include all of your relevant html and css in a snippet so we can see what you have so far and help you get to your goal.

Comment: Could you also post some **html**, so i could bring all together ?

Comment: On **transition**-attribute of CSS-class **.am-secta**,  you should replace **ease-out** with **ease-in-out**

Comment: ok, please check it out

Comment: @tstrand66  ok, please check it sir

Comment: @tstrand66  ok, please check it out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition check out this question on transitioning a background image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you are looking for this:

```
 .am-secta {
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      background-color: #212121;
      z-index: 1;
      transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .am-secta:hover{  
     background-image:linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(33,33,33,1) 0%, rgba(29,185,84,0.5) 100%), 
     url("http://www.piyushcares.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/homepagevid.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat; /*if you have full size image then use no-repeat*/
     background-position: center center top;
     background-size:cover;
    }
```